# jquery autocomplete to return custom list?

Tags: jquery, list, autocomplete, fixed

I'm using the jquery autocomplete plugin and it works great.

However, I want to customize my data such that I can return a fixed set of data.

Example: The typical way it works - you just in a letter like 'a' and it returns matching 'j' ('aloe', 'babe', 'car').

However, I want a functionality so that,whatever you type in, it returns a fixed list like 'one', 'two', three' - no matter what letters you type.

How do I modify to do this?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the purpose of autocomplete? You're probably better off using a `select` element.

Comment: Yeah, that's not an autocomplete, because it's not completing anything. What specifically are you trying to restrict/enable?

Comment: I can do this using a select element, but I want the effect of having a drop-down list on a textfield (similar to an autocomplete). Yeah, the restrict/enable is the feature I want.